# How do I style dynamic contents inside a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I'm doing this in JavaScript :

```
.......
if (!isNaN(num))
    document.getElementById("isNum").innerHTML = num +" is a number";
......
```

Then HTML :

```
<div>
    <button onclick="checknum()">Insert anything : </button>
    <p id="isNum"></p>  
</div>
```

The output (suppose input is 3):

```
3 is a number
```

So the question is :

How can I color, maybe by css, the variable into Javascript, the output something like:

***3*** `is a number`

Comment: How do you color something in HTML (or css)? Use this exact way to set the relevant HTML (when you use `.innerHTML = "..."` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your `num` by span :

```
document.getElementById("isNum").innerHTML = '<span>'+num+"</span> is a number";
```

Then add a css rule for this specific span inside paragraph that have id `#isNum` :

```
#isNum span{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var num = 3;

if (!isNaN(num))
    document.getElementById("isNum").innerHTML = '<span>'+num+"</span> is a number";
```

```css
#isNum span{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="isNum"></p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em) to *emphasize* the input would be more appropriate in this case.

```html
<p id="isNum"><em>3</em> is a Number</p>
```

Here is a sample snippet to work with (hope it is self-explanatory).

Idea is to *wrap* the value which we need to be *emphasize* in an [`inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)  element (for example, `span` or `em`).

Note that [`<b>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) or [`i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i) or [`<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em) elements could also be used to get the results.

```js
function checknum() {

  // Get the `output` element
  var outputElement = document.querySelector("#isNum");

  // Get the `input` value 
  var num = document.querySelector("#numValue").value;

  // Validate: do we have a value and is it a number?
  var isNumber = num.length > 0 && !isNaN(num);

  // Format the HTML string to output
  // Wrap the value inside an inline element so that we could style it separately 
  var outputHTML = "<em>" + num + "</em>";

  // Output
  outputElement.innerHTML = isNumber ?
    outputHTML + " is a number" :
    "Not valid";
}
```

```css
#isNum > em {
  color: blue;
}
#isNum > span {
  /* incase we go with span */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="numValue" />
  <button onclick="checknum()">Insert anything</button>
  <p id="isNum"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("isNum").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>" + num +"</span> is a number";
```

Or (and this is generally considered a better practice) you could set a class on that span rather than an inline style. Then define the color for that class in your CSS, wherever that lives for your page.

JS:

```
innerHTML = "<span class='number'>" + num +"</span> is a number";
```

CSS:

```
.number { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an element

```
element.innerHTML = "<span class='blue'>" + num +"</span> is a number";
```

And style that class

```js
function checknum() {
  var num  = prompt('Insert anything');
  var element = document.getElementById("isNum");
  
  if (!isNaN(num))
    element.innerHTML = "<span class='red'>" + num + "</span> is a number";
}
```

```css
.red {color : red}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="checknum()">Insert anything : </button>
    <p id="isNum"></p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   if (!isNaN(num))
    document.getElementById("isNum").innerHTML = '<span class="red">' + num +"</span> is a number";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap the number with a DOM element

Suppose this is the rendered HTML

```
<p id="isNum"><span class="num-color"> 1</span> is a color</p>
```

then add CSS

```
.num-color {
 color: yellow;
}
```

In order to get the HTML above, change your JavaScript code to this:

```
document.getElementById("isNum").innerHTML = '<span class="num-color">' + num + '</span>' +' is a number';
```